# rustのジェネリクスを使った実装で、トレイトの関数がnot foundになってしまう

Tags: rust

もともとjuliaで書いていた数値計算プログラムをrustに移植しようとしています.
rust for beginnerを読みながら実装をすすめていたのですが,　トレイト境界について誤解しているらしく
思ったような挙動になりません.
具体的には, 添付コードのb_to_wがnot foundになってしまいます. Tで境界として, Wenoトレイトを指定しているのですが
これではメソッド呼び出しできないのでしょうか?
もしくは抽象化の方法がrustとして間違っているのでしょうか.
回答お願いいたします.

```
trait Reconstruct {}

trait Scheme<const N: usize> {
    fn compute(st: &[f64; N]) -> f64;
    fn compute_l(&self, st: &[f64; N]) -> f64;
    fn compute_r(st: &[f64; N]) -> f64;
}

trait Weno {
    const D0: f64 = 2.0;
    const D1: f64 = 2.0;
    const D2: f64 = 2.0;

    fn b_to_w(b1: f64, b2: f64, b3: f64) -> [f64; 3];
}

impl<T: Weno> Scheme<5> for T {
    fn compute(st: &[f64; 5]) -> f64 {
        todo!()
    }

    fn compute_l(&self, st: &[f64; 5]) -> f64 {
        let [qmm, qm, q, qp, qpp] = st;

        let q0 = 1. / 3. * qmm - 7. / 6. * qm + 11. / 6. * q;
        let q1 = -1. / 6. * qm + 5. / 6. * q + 1. / 3. * qp;
        let q2 = 1. / 3. * q + 5. / 6. * qp - 1. / 6. * qpp;

        let b0 =
            13. / 12. * (qmm - 2. * qm + q).powf(2.) + 1. / 4. * (qmm - 4. * qm + 3. * q).powf(2.);
        let b1 = 13. / 12. * (qm - 2. * q + qp).powf(2.) + 1. / 4. * (qm - qp).powf(2.);
        let b2 =
            13. / 12. * (q - 2. * qp + qpp).powf(2.) + 1. / 4. * (3. * q - 4. * qp + qpp).powf(2.);

        let d0 = 0.1;
        let d1 = 0.6;
        let d2 = 0.3;
        let [w0, w1, w2] = self.b_to_w(b0, b1, b2);
        q0 * w0 + q1 * w1 + q2 * w2
    }

    fn compute_r(st: &[f64; 5]) -> f64 {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct WenoZ;

impl Weno for WenoZ {
    fn b_to_w(b0: f64, b1: f64, b2: f64) -> [f64; 3] {
        let t = (b2 - b0).abs();
        let e = 1.0e-20;
        let bz0 = (b0 + e) / (b0 + t + e);
        let bz1 = (b1 + e) / (b1 + t + e);
        let bz2 = (b2 + e) / (b2 + t + e);
        let a0 = Self::D0 / bz0;
        let a1 = Self::D1 / bz1;
        let a2 = Self::D2 / bz2;
        let sum = a0 + a1 + a2;
        [a0 / sum, a1 / sum, a2 / sum]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b_to_w` は引数に `&self` を取らないので

```
        let [w0, w1, w2] = Self::b_to_w(b0, b1, b2);
```

とすれば呼び出せます。あるいは同じ意味になりますが `T::b_to_w` でもいけます（`Self`は今`T`のことを指している）

Comment: ありがとうございます. 関連関数とメソッドを混同していたようです.